# How to set new height of class="container" to end of data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

How to set new height of class="container" to end of data ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
.absolute1 {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.absolute2 {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    left: 210px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
  </style>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".container" ).each(function() {
        var newHeight = 0, $this = $( this );
        $.each( $this.children(), function() {
            newHeight += $( this ).height();
        });
        $this.height( newHeight );
    });
});
});//]]>  

</script>

<div class="container">
       <div class="absolute1">
           Testing absoluteTesting absoluteTesting absoluteTesting absoluteTesting absolute<br />
           Even more testing absolven more testing absolven more testing absolven more testing absolven more testing absolute<br />
       </div>    
           <div class="absolute2">
           Testing absoluteTesting absoluteTesting absoluteTesting absoluteTesting absolute<br />
           Even more testing absolven more testing absolven more testing absolven more testing absolven more testing absolute<br />
       </div>   
</div>

------------------footer text------------------
```

Comment: What do you mean by "end of data"?

Comment: Side note: You don't need `$(window).load()` AND `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

use jquery **.outerHeight()** function

//The top and bottom padding and border are always included in the .outerHeight() calculation; if the includeMargin argument is set to true, the margin (top and bottom) is also included.

u will get new height of element then set this value to element css using jquery

Comment: do you have some demo ?